# How to reduce an integral with square root of cubic function into an elliptic integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I need to calculate the following ntegral:
$$\int \frac{t  }{\sqrt{2 t^3 - 3 t^2 + 6 C}} dt$$
where $C$ is a constant to be determined later, so I cannot look for roots of the polynomial in the denominator. I've found that integrals involving $R(t,\sqrt{P(t)})$, where $R$ is a rational function of its arguments and $P$ is a polynomial of degree 3 or 4 with no repeated roots, can be reduced to elliptic integrals. I've also found that it is sometimes done with Moebius transformation, however I can't find any general "walkthrough" and my attempts to express the above integral in terms of elliptic integrals have failed. I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: I think that this could be difficult. Even writing $2t^3-3t^2+6C=2(t-r_1)(t-r_2)(t-r_3)$ and later using the product of the roots makes the problem quite hard (at least to me). Moreover, I suspect that you would get more than one elliptic integral as a result.

Comment: It does look that pretty, at least what [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+t%2Fsqrt(2t%5E3-3t%5E2%2B6C)) produces.

Comment: @mrtaurho. Change $C$ to $c$ in WA. I do not know what it is doing with $C$ : very strange !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It does seem to change [that much](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+t%2Fsqrt(2t%5E3-3t%5E2%2B6c)). But yes indeed, the output looks strange anyway.

Comment: @mrtaurho. Yes, this is what I did and obtained. I wonder how was interpreted $C$. Any idea ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Firstly I thought about something like a constant. However, even though by setting $C=x$ and clarifying to integrate w.r.t. to $t$ the weird structure of the output remains $($see here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+t%2Fsqrt(2t%5E3-3t%5E2%2B6x)+dt $)$. Do you know what the # symbol denotes?

Comment: This symbol is used as a dummy variable in a polynomial you search for the roots of. Just type **solve x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0** and see.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a method for expressing a general elliptic integral in terms of elliptic integrals of the $1^{st}$, $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ kind can be found in H. Hancock - ["Lectures on the theory of elliptic functions" , p. 180](https://archive.org/details/lecturestheorell00hancrich/page/n211):

For a general case of integral of type:
$$\int\frac{t \; \text{d}t}{\sqrt{a t^3 + 3 b t^2 + 3 c t + d}}$$
we may introduce a substitution:
$$t=m \cdot z + n$$
with
$$ m=\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{a}} \;, \; \; \; n=-\frac{b}{a}$$
what results in:
$$\int\frac{t \; \text{d}t}{\sqrt{a t^3 + 3 b t^2 + 3 c t + d}}=
A \int\frac{\text{d}z}{\sqrt{4 z^3 - g_2 z - g_3}}+
B \int\frac{z\; \text{d}z}{\sqrt{4 z^3 - g_2 z - g_3}}$$
where $A,B,g_2, g_3$ are constants. The first integral on the right-hand side of the above formula is an elliptic integral of the first kind in Weierstrass normal form and may be expressed in terms of Weierstrass $\wp$ function, while the other one is the elliptic integral of the second kind in Weierstrass normal form which may be expressed in terms of  Weierstrass $\zeta$-function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this reduction is in

*Hancock, F. H.*, [**Elliptic integrals.**](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000615533), New York: Wiley, 104 S (1917). [ZBL46.0620.06](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:46.0620.06).

But my memory may be wrong, it was many years ago that I read this.

Comment: Thank you - it's good to know that this book is available online. I'll check it, yet it may take some time :)